# How to check for redundancy of a specific string in MS Word?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

H ey there,

I need to check whether a certain string is found twice inside my MS Word document.

My approach up till now was to use the .Find method to search for the string and if .Execute is true then to increase a counter. If the counter is > 1 a message box informs the user of the redundancy.

The code searches for the string and finds it correctly, however, the .Find method doesn't seem to loop on its own until it has parsed the whole document once. Therefore the counter is always 1 and the message box wont pop up.

Do any of you have an idea how to loop this code? I can't seem to find a fitting break condition...

best regards

daZza

Code:

```
Dim wrdRange As Object
Dim searchString As String
Dim redundancyCounter As Integer


redundancyCounter = 0

Set wrdRange = wrdDoc.Content
wrdRange.Find.ClearFormatting
wrdRange.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting


With wrdRange.Find
.Text = searchString
.Forward = True
.wrap = wdFindStop
.Format = False
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = False
.MatchWildcards = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False
End With

If wrdRange.Find.Execute Then
redundancyCounter = redundancyCounter + 1
Debug.Print redundancyCounter

If redundancyCounter > 1 Then
    MsgBox "Für diese Version existiert bereits eine Tabelle in der Änderungshistorie!" & vbNewLine & _
    "Bitte überprüfe die Änderungshistorie manuell und nimm ggf. Änderungen vor.", vbCritical, "Warnung, mögliche Redundanz erkannt!"

End If
End If
```

**Edit: Suggestion with MatchWildcards (throws false positive when no redundancy)**

```
With wrdRange.Find
 .Text = searchString & "*" & searchString
 .Forward = True
 .wrap = wdFindStop
 .Format = False
 .MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = False
.MatchWildcards = True
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False
End With

If wrdRange.Find.Execute Then

    MsgBox "Für diese Version existiert bereits eine Tabelle in der Änderungshistorie!" & vbNewLine & _
    "Bitte überprüfe die Änderungshistorie manuell und nimm ggf. Änderungen vor.", vbCritical, "Warnung, mögliche Redundanz erkannt!"


End If
```

Comment: Why not do a WIldcard find? e.g. if the text to find is "mytext", use .MatchWildcards = True and search for "mytext*mytext"

Comment: Works partly, but throws a false positive when there is no redundancy. Updated my OP

Comment: OK, what happens when you use the following? I didn't understand what you meant by "until it has parsed the whole document once"

While wrdRange.Find.Execute
  redundancyCounter = redundancyCounter + 1
Wend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
While wrdRange.Find.Execute 
  redundancyCounter = redundancyCounter + 1 
Wend
```